# How to remove rows in pandas dataframe column that contain the hyphen character?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame given as follows:

```
new_dict = {'Area_sqfeet': '[1002, 322, 420-500,300,1.25acres,100-250,3.45 acres]'}

df = pd.DataFrame([new_dict])
df.head()
```

I want to remove hyphen values and change acres to sqfeet in this dataframe.
How may I do it efficiently?

Comment: In your example of 100-250, you mean totally remove that value (along with 420-500), like delete them? Just want to be clear you are not just trying to remove the hyphen

Comment: Also you are creating a dataframe with a single row!

Comment: nice question. List comprehension is the winner here. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Use list comprehension:**

```
mylist = ["1002", "322", "420-500","300","1.25acres","100-250","3.45 acres"]
# ['1002', '322', '420-500', '300', '1.25acres', '100-250', '3.45 acres']
```

**Step 1: Remove hyphens**

```
filtered_list  = [i for i in mylist if "-" not in i] # remove hyphens
```

**Step 2: Convert acres to sqfeet**:

```
final_list = [i if 'acres' not in i else eval(i.split('acres')[0])*43560 for i in filtered_list] # convert to sq foot

#['1002', '322', '300', 54450.0, 150282.0]
```

**Also, if you want to keep the "sqfeet" next tot he converted values use this:**

```
final_list = [i if 'acres' not in i else "{} sqfeet".format(eval(i.split('acres')[0])*43560) for i in filtered_list]

# ['1002', '322', '300', '54450.0 sqfeet', '150282.0 sqfeet']
```

Comment: I don't want to remove only the hyphen but to delete the value completely.                                         and want to convert 1.25 acres to 54450  (unit conversion sq feet)

Answer (score -1):

Here's something that might get you going in the right direction:

```
import pandas as pd

col_name = 'Area_sqfeet'

# per comment on your question, you need to make a dataframe with more
# than one row, your original question only had one row
new_list = ["1002", "322", "420-500","300","1.25acres","100-250","3.45 acres"]

df = pd.DataFrame(new_list)
df.columns = ["Area_sqfeet"]

# once you have the df as strings, here's how to remove the ones with hyphens
df = df[df["Area_sqfeet"].str.contains("-")==False]
print(df.head())
```

Comment: and want to convert 1.25 acres to 54450  (unit conversion sq feet)